# Interaction H2 database with node.js

Tags: node.js, h2

friends!
I have an appendix on node.js. As there is earlier created and working database on h2. Help to find interaction possibility please. That is it is necessary from the appendix on node.js to be able to do inquiries in base on H2.
Thanks for the help!